# Unable to execute initial Android Wear Hello World App in eclipse

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat, wear-os, eclipse-luna

After intial Eclipse Luna setup when I try to run the intial Hello World app in the Android Wear emulator, its getting stopped showing "You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar" error in logcat.Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. I solved it by running the application in full screen mode, I do not think this is the best solution, but it worked, although this does not have the action bar.

In you onCreate method add this before the setContentView.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks blablabla2424 and jlapenna for your suggestions,atlast I am able to execute my first apk on wearable emulator

Comment: could you pls suggest me how to use this fullscreen stuff with phonegap

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're not using a theme that includes an action bar. Consider using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Theme.DeviceDefault as your android:theme

Here the full steps on how to do it using eclipse.
https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d