# Unfortunately,MyFirstApp has stopped on AVD emulator for samsung S3

Tags: android-emulator, samsung-mobile, android-virtual-device

I am newbie to android and have started with the [beginner tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator) of building and running MYFirstApp on AVD emulator for samsung S3,I have went through posts related to the emulator configuration for samsung s3 and configured my emulator settings as shown below

[image: Emulator_Configuration_samsungS3]

after this I launched the emulator which appears as below
[image]

and then I made to run MyFirstApp the emulator shows as below
[image]

The logcat shows as
[image]
[image]
Can someone please help in figuring out the error and to correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: what the error say? "You cannot combine........ swipe dismissal and the action bar."... can you post the entire line?

Comment: Seems like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567836/unable-to-execute-intial-android-wear-hello-world-app-in-eclipse